# WP showing two active menu items at the same time

Tags: wordpress

One of the pages on my site is setup to display posts from a specific category. When that category is active, the blog menu item also shows as active, displaying two active menu items at the same time. I've tried excluding the category, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Please share some code or more information.

Answer (score -1):

**It may be a hotlinking issue.**
s
You'll see from this site at http://www.wildpop.ca (Wildpop dot.ca), when you choose "SEO" from the menu, you are directed to what appears to be the "Monthly Packages" page. The SEO link in the menu does not have it's own page. It is a direct link to a section named (seo_direct) that is contained in a different page, but when you look at the menu again - both menu options are highlighted as "Active Page".

Make sure this isn't the issue for you.